# how to send json data to server and get Json response in android?

Tags: java, android

how to send json data to server and get json response in android using HttpURLConnection (get, post, put, delete)?
the url like = http://maxxapi.webname.com/oauth/token_access

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** : Since question doesn't ask for a specific error, this is a simple basic code to show how to send JSON data to a server (given IP)

Lets assume that we have 3 text fields with *`f_name`*, *`l_name`*, *`age`* & also a button which will trigger `onClick` method on button press.

**Below is the code** 
This should be in the activity which the button is in.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    JSONObject payLoad = new JSONObject();
    try {
        payLoad.put("first_name", f_name.getText().toString());
        payLoad.put("last_name", l_name.getText().toString());
        payLoad.put("age", age.getText().toString());

        new SendPostRequest.execute("http://123.456.789.78:8080/address1/address2", postData.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is a new Class that responsible for send the response.

```
private class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String postData = "";

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection= null;
        try {

            httpConnection= (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream outputStream= new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes("PostData=" + params[1]);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                char currentData = (char) inputStreamData;
                inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                postData += currentData;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpConnection!= null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return postData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to send http requests,i suggest you to try OkHttpClient or Retrofit